# How do I link to a LABEL in org-mode?

Tags: hyperlink, label, org-mode

In org-mode, I have defined a figure+caption like this:

```
#+CAPTION: My great figure
#+LABEL: fig:myfigure
[[myfigure.png]]
```

How do I write "See figure [myfigure]"?  I've found the following syntax:

```
See figure \ref{fig:myfigure}
```

but this looks ugly in the source file.  In particular, you cannot use it for actually jumping to the figure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a very recent org-mode, you can use `#+name:`, see:
http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/62644/focus=62646

```
#+CAPTION: My great figure
#+LABEL: fig:myfigure
#+name: fig:myfigure
[[test.png]]

See figure [[fig:myfigure][test]].
```

This works for me to jump from the link , but has no effect when exporting, I'm afraid...

Comment: This seems to be as good as it can get currently.  The rest must be fixed in org-mode.

Comment: The specifics of how this works are explained in the Org Manual [here.](http://orgmode.org/manual/Internal-links.html)

Answer (score 9):

You actually don't need `'#+NAME'`, it works fine if you use `'#+LABEL'`, which won't break your short-caption for list of figures.

Orgmode does now offer a `'jumpable'`, enumerated or link with name of your choice in the exported (latex, html) text if you link with:

```
see figure [[fig:myfigure]].
```

or

```
see figure [[fig:myfigure][figurenameintext]].
```

I would have added this as a comment, but I don't have the reputation yet.

--
In response to your comment (still can't comment): you do need the `'#+NAME'` for it to jump within the .org source file; as mentioned in the [manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Internal-links.html), and i also just confirmed that works. Not sure about the short-captions in the latest version.

Comment: Ok well formatted answer i will + you so you be able to comment.

Comment: In my test, with org-mode from git, if I click on the link *in the org-mode file* it does not jump to the referred figure. Should it?

Comment: This does not work for me. The link you posted also doesn't list this feature.